# Which are the 118 worlds as described in Fifteen verses of Wisdom?

Tags: identification-request, shaivism, kashmiri-shaivism

One of the verses from Fifteen Verses of Wisdom (bodhapancadasika) by Abhinavagupta, the great master of all aspects of Kashmir Shaivism, is as follows:

> In this way the Lord, Bhairava, the essence of all being, has held in
>   His own way in His own nature, the three great energies: the energy of
>   will (iccha-sakti), the energy of action (kriya-sakti), and the energy
>   of knowledge (jnana-sakti). These three energies are just like that
>   trident which is the three-fold lotus. And seated on this lotus is
>   Lord Bhairava, **who is the nature of the whole universe of 118
>   worlds**.

**My question:** Which are these 118 worlds being referred here?

Comment: Off topic clarification from me: Difference between Brahman and Parabrahman?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS This might help you https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/what-is-the-relation-difference-between-brahman%e0%a4%ac%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%ae-parabrahm%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%ac%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%ae/9729#9729

Comment: Based on the English translation, I was unable to locate the corresponding Sanskrit verses. What is your source? This is the Sanskrit text: http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/6_sastra/3_phil/saiva/bodhpanu.htm The only thing that comes close is the first half of the fifteenth verse: "ittham icchākalājñānaśaktiśūlāmbujāśritaḥ"

Comment: @GabeHiemstra It is the 15th verse, the one you stated ittham icchākalājñānaśaktiśūlāmbujāśritaḥ |
bhairavaḥ sarvabhāvānāṃ svabhāvaḥ pariśīlyate || 15 ||

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Shaktism, as well as in Shaivism, there are 36 Tattvas. Shiva/Shakti, Vidya, Maya, Purusha, Prakriti, Iswara, etc to the Panchabhutas are these 36 Tattvas.

These Tattvas are again grouped into Shuddha (pure), Shuddhashuddha (mixed) and Ashuddha (impure) categories.

Now, certain Bhuvanas (or worlds) are assigned to several of these Tattvas. That is, the Tattvas own certain Bhuvanas. The Tattvas also have respective Kalas (kalA i.e part) associated with them.

The complete list of all the Bhuvanas owned by these Tattvas are as follows:

> - Shiva Tattva's Bhuvanas (10 in number) - Anashrita, Anatha, Ananta, Vyomrupini, Vyapini, Urdhagamini, Mochika, Rotika, Dipika and Indhika.
> - Shakti Tattva's Bhuvanas (5) - Shantyatita, Shanti, Vidya, Pratishtha and Nivritti. (Vaindavpura is the alternate name for these
>     Bhuvanas)
> - Sadashiva Tattva's Bhuvanas (1) - Sadashiva Bhuvana.
> - Iswara Tattva's Bhuvanas (8) - Shikhandi, Shrikantha, Trimurti, Ekanetra, Ekarudra, Shivottama, Sukshma and Ananta.
> - Suddhavidya Tattva's Bhuvanas (9) - Manonmani, Sarvabhutadamani, Balapramathini, Balavikarini, Kalavikarini, Kali, Raudri, Jyeshtha and
>     Vama.
> - Maya  (8) - Angushtamatra, Ishana, Ekekshana, Ekapingala, Udbhava, Bhava, Vamadeva, and Mahadyuti.
> - Kala (this is KAla) Tattva's (2) - Shikesh and Ekavira.
> - KalA Tattva (this is KalA) (2) - Panchantaka and Shura.
> - Vidya Tattva (2) - Pinga and Jyoti.
> - Niyati Tattva (2) - Samvarta and Krodha.
> - Raga Tattva (5) - Ekashiva, Ananta, Aja, Umapati and Prachanda.
> - Purusha Tattva (6) - Ekavira, Ishana, Bhava, Isha, Ugra, Bhima and Vam.
> - Prakriti Tattva (8) - Shrikantha, Aum, Kaumara, Vaishnava, Brahma, Bhairava. Krita and Akrita.
> - Buddhi Tattva (8) - Brahma, Prajesh, Saumya, Aindra, Gandharva, Yaksha, Rakshasha and Pishacha.
> - Ahamkara Tattva (1) - Sthuleswara
> - Bhuvanas owned by Manas (mind) and Pancha Gyana Indriyas (1) - Sthuleswara.
> - Pancha Karma Indriyas (1) - Shankukarna
> - Pancha Tanmatra's (5) - Kalanjara, Mandaleswara, Makota, Dravinda and Chakalanda.
> - Akasha Tattva (8) - Sthanu, Swarnaksha, Bhadrakarna, Gokarna, Mahalaya, Avimukta, Rudrakoti and Vastrapada.
> - Vayu Tattva (8) - Bhimeswara, Mahendra, Attahasa, Vimalesh, Nala, Nakala, Kurukshetra and Gaya.
> - Teja Tattva  (8) - Bhairava, Kedara, Mahakala, Madhyadesha, Amratak, Jalpesh, Shrishaila, Harishchandra.
> - Apa Tattva (8) - Lakulisha, Parabhurti Dindi, Mundi, Vidhi, Pushkara, Naimisha, Prabhash and Amaresha.
> - Prithvi Tattva - Highest no of Bhuvanas are assigned to it - around 108.

So, if we count the number of Bhuvanas, till the Apa (or water) Tattva, we have **116** of them. Now, add those of the Prithvi Tattva and the total comes around **234**.

So, these are the names of all the Bhuvanas that are there in Shaktism as well as in Kashmiri Shaivism. Now, I am not sure which of these they have counted in and which they have left out to come to the total of 118.

A vague list of these Bhuvanas are also given in Kalika Agama (I have the verses) but we can not count the precise number of Bhuvanas from that list.

[Source of the info given here is a book that I've called **"Sri Sri Dashamahavidya Tattva Rahasya"** by Srimat Swami Paramatmanandanatha Bhairava Giri. The chapter which have all these details is "Sri Bhuvaneswari Murti Rahasya" (the mystery behind the depiction of Bhuvaneswari)].

As you can guess, Goddess Bhuvaneswari (as the name itself suggests: Bhuvana+Iswari) is the supreme controller of all these worlds (Bhuvanas) that exist.

Comment: This is correct. Also see my answer for the correct IAST transliteration as well as the full context as to how these worlds should be interpreted.

Comment: Well my answer is complete and comprehensive and after that what is thr to see in ur answer? I hv even given names of all the Bhuvanas that are associated with the Tattvas. If I want I can also give the correct transliteration it's not a big deal because I type upon seeing from Sanskrit books only. But I can't devote so much of time/effort. Also I don't search on Google to get answers, I answer only when I hv prior knowledge about the subject and here I hv read about these Bhuvanas already in the the book that I hv mentioned in the answer @GabeHiemstra

Comment: "after that what is thr to see in ur answer", how about a link to the full list of these worlds including a more detailed description of their Kālas and Tattvas, a comparison of the first and second interpretation, correct IAST transliteration. The answer also contains more background information regarding their original source. I'm not criticizing your answer I'm saying my answer is more detailed, contains source links and contains background information which is something the OP should have noticed seeing it was posted 5 days earlier...

Comment: Besides, transliteration is not a big deal? Seriously? First of all, confusion regarding Kala, KAla and KalA. Second: It is impossible to determine gender. Third: You used Hindi style transliteration, skipping letters such as Prajesh = Prajeśa. And also the w is non-existent in Sanskrit. It is simply incorrect Sanskrit.

Comment: We can not do that much here.. it is not mandatory for me to do actually.. I know all the correct words because I'm typing from Sanskrit books only.. Also I'm a Bengali so Sanskrit comes quite easy for us..See we are not professionally working for this site.. If I was I would hv given a proper transliteration too.  @GabeHiemstra

Comment: Ok I understand. I can give you some recommendations for easy tools you can install and quickly type IAST with your keyboard. If you are interested, let me know! Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: "how about a link to the full list of these worlds including a more detailed description of their Kālas and Tattvas, a comparison of the first and second interpretation, correct IAST transliteration." -- well I hvn't chkd ur answer before writing mine. I do not even read fully the Qs that I'm answering what to say of reading other people's answers.. well I don't mostly and that can taken as one of my shortcomings. I already knew about these Bhuvanas from various Tantra related books that I hv and I hv simply reproduced the info here.. @GabeHiemstra

Comment: Ok thanks for ur help but for the time being I'll stick to what I am doing... @GabeHiemstra

Comment: No problem, its not your fault, but the fault of the OP for (obviously) not reading answers in full. Please, keep on doing what you do. @Rickross

Answer (score 2):

According to the Non-dual Śaivism Tantras (Trika), the Bhuvanas (Sanskrit for ‘worlds’ or ‘planes of reality’) are 118 [(source)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=H0YwDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT154&dq=%22bhuvana%22%20%22118%22&hl=nl&pg=PT154). The [Sanskrit text](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/6_sastra/3_phil/saiva/bodhpanu.htm) of the bodhapancadasika doesn't mention these 118 worlds directly, but (I'm guessing that) since both this text and the Tantraloka are written by the same author, it is automatically assumed as being 118 worlds.

There is second interpretation of 226 worlds. The difference lies in the various interpretations of grouping the worlds.

### List of 226 and 118 worlds:

Fortunately, there is a reliable source available showing a table of these two lists. In short:—As Guru Gabriel Pradīpaka shows, bhuvanas are ‘worlds’ manifested by padas (“Full-fledged Words”). Pada in turn, is “composed of Mantras or Seed Syllables”. Mantras (seed syllables) are the result of transformed varṇas (individual letters) which manifest the alphabet.

To get a full understanding you should read the full article, starting at the beginning:

> [The universal manifestation according to Trika](https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/trika-the-six-courses-1-non-dual-shaivism-of-kashmir/502)

The same page also lists the names of all these words ([here](https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/trika-the-six-courses-1-non-dual-shaivism-of-kashmir/502#SummaryChart)), which I'm reluctant to just bluntly copy/paste here. And again, you should read the article from the beginning.

### Further reading:

Chapter eight of the Abhinava’s Tantraloka discusses these worlds:

> TĀ 8 explores the various worlds (bhuvana) and is dependent on a number of sources, in particular the Svacchandatantra.
>
> [(source)](https://archive.org/details/AbhinavaguptaTheKulaRitualAsElaboratedInChapter29OfTheTantralokaJohnR.Dupuche/page/n61), p. 48 n54

Unfortunately, I do not know of any English translation of the Svacchandatantra. I did come across this paragraph from a Thesis on the ST by William James:

> The tenth book describes the Śaiva cosmology, or more properly one of the six paths (adhvā) or modes in which Śivaḥ emanates the universe, viz. that of the worlds (bhuvana-) . Byfar the longest book in Svacchandatantram, it represents the Śaiva assimilation and extension of the entire Purāṇic cosmology.
>
> …
>
> Abhinavaguptaḥ based his presentation of the path of the worlds in Tantrālokaḥ almost entirely on this book of Svacchandatantram, and therefore indicates that Svacchandatantram must have already acquired at his time a reputation as the preeminent and exhaustive scriptural revelation of the Śaiva cosmology.
>
> [(source)](https://archive.org/details/SvacchndaTantraWilliamJamesArrajThesis/page/n223) p. 218

Finally, as Navjivan Rastogi, in his “Introduction to the Tantrāloka” states:—Abhinava learned a lot of this bhuvana science from Bhūtirāja:

> Bhūtirāja  seems to have excelled inmany branches of learning in addition to the dualistic-monistic discipline. Perhaps his full name was Bhūtirājamiśra. He seems to have initiated Abhinava in the science of the ‘size of all the regions’ (bhuvanas) and ‘purifiability of all of them’ and propounded the theory of hundred Rudras (Śatarudras) in the context of the treatment of Bhuvamādhvan and Pratiṣṭhā Kalā.
>
> [(source)](https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToTheTantralokaAStudyAndStructureNavjivanRastogiVol1MLBD/page/n67) p.41

Comment: Pretty interesting and informative links out there!