# What are some scientifically proven things from Hinduism?

Tags: science, truth

There are various ancient Hindu practices and philosophies which today have been proven by modern science. Such as:

- Yoga
- Meditation
- Breathwork
- Celibacy (Brahmacharya)
- Various Ayurvedic techniques
- Multiverse Theory
- Simulation theory (concept of Maya and Lila)
- Other philosophies which match up with modern quantum physics ideas

Can you name any others?

Comment: How is celibacy proven? And the same for maya and lila? Also, in Hinduism there is nothing matching about quantum mechanics?

Comment: The multiverse theory did not came from Hinduism btw.

Comment: Modern science would always demand an empirical evidence ,lest the credibility is doubted. The topics listed in the question, do not seem to have parallels in modern science.If so , how is it explained?Yet  some modern concepts can be discovered to occur as part of ancient texts . Eg.Some of the modern math  concepts  occur in shulba sutras. They are systematically dealt in them

Comment: You may choose to edit/refine your question, and support them with any factual statement/assertion

Comment: Might be a duplicate of the following but it is closed too https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17442/4732

Comment: @Wikash_ The concept of [bhuvana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32737/647) is similar to multiverse.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I did not say that there are similar concepts of this in Hinduism. I tried to explain that the concept of a multiverse was already known before hinduism. Also, a multiverse is not scientifically proven to exist.

Comment: @Wikash_ FYI, the concept was introduced 2000 or may be more than 2000 years ago in Hinduism. Also fyi,  In Hinduism, science and spirituality co-exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some scientific facts described in Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/what-are-some-scientific-facts-described-in-hindu-scriptures)

Answer (score 1):

Yogi's are known to observe their own body with utmost attention and were able to find out things about the body which modern medicine and science also found out.

One such thing is [nasal cycle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_cycle).

> The nasal cycle was studied and discussed in the **ancient Indian yoga**
> **of literature of pranayama**. In the modern western literature, it
> was first described by the German physician Richard Kayser in 1895.

[image]

> *A CT scan showing evidence of the nasal cycle. The more patent airway*
> *is on the right of the image; the swollen turbinates congesting the*
> *left.*

> The nasal cycle is the unconscious alternating partial
> congestion and decongestion of the nasal cavities in humans and other
> animals. This results in greater airflow through one nostril with
> periodic alternation between the nostrils. It is a physiological
> congestion of the nasal conchae, also called the nasal turbinates
> (curled bony projections within the nasal cavities), due to selective
> activation of one half of the autonomic nervous system by the
> hypothalamus. It should not be confused with pathological nasal
> congestion.

Also notice the similarity of this with Anulom Vilom Pranayama.